# C# BeginSend and BeginReceive issues in socket connection

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, sockets, server

I'm using both BeginSend and BeginReceive in my C# application. It is a client listener and will only receive data from a server. I'm using BeginReceive to get the data.

But I found out that only doing receiving won't be enough to keep the connection alive and stable. So, I've decided let my application to always ping the server to keep the connection alive by using BeginSend.

Below is my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataProcess();
}

public Socket _serverSocket = null;
private byte[] _recieveBuffer = new byte[128];
byte[] AllBytes;
void DataProcess()
{
    //TimeSpan ts;
    try
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (_serverSocket == null || sockState == MySocketState.Disconnected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect...");
            SetupServer();
        }
        else
        {
            AllBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(COM_DeviceIsOnline);
            _serverSocket.BeginSend(AllBytes, 0, AllBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void SetupServer()
{
    try
    {
        _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _serverSocket.Connect(_sIP, Int32.Parse(_sPort));
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    if (_serverSocket.Connected)
    {
        sockState = MySocketState.Connected;
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("svrConnect();");
        Console.WriteLine("Server connected...");
        _serverSocket.BeginReceive(_recieveBuffer, 0, _recieveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }
}

void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int bytesSent = _serverSocket.EndSend(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    try
    {
        if (_serverSocket == null)
            _serverSocket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;

        //Check how much bytes are recieved and call EndRecieve to finalize handshake
        int recieved = _serverSocket.EndReceive(AR);

        if (recieved <= 0)
        {
            CloseSocket();
            return;
        }

        //Copy the recieved data into new buffer , to avoid null bytes
        byte[] recData = new byte[recieved];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(_recieveBuffer, 0, recData, 0, recieved);
        string strData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData);
        Console.WriteLine(strData);

        //Process data here the way you want , all your bytes will be stored in recData

        int nSOHPos = -1;
        int nSTXPos = -1;
        int nETXPos = -1;
        int nEOTPos = -1;

        nSOHPos = Array.IndexOf(recData, SOH);
        nSTXPos = Array.IndexOf(recData, STX);
        nETXPos = Array.IndexOf(recData, ETX);
        nEOTPos = Array.IndexOf(recData, EOT);

        if ((nSOHPos == -1) || (nSTXPos == -1) || (nETXPos == -1) || (nEOTPos == -1))
        {
            CloseSocket();
            return;
        }

        if (nSOHPos > nSTXPos ||
                nSTXPos > nETXPos ||
                nETXPos > nEOTPos)
        {
            CloseSocket();
            return;
        }

        if ((nETXPos - nSTXPos) < 6)
        {
            CloseSocket();
            return;
        }

        string _sCommand = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, nSTXPos + 6, 2);

        if ((_sCommand == "CN") || (_sCommand == "CL") || (_sCommand == "CR"))
        {
            nDept = int.Parse(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, nSTXPos + 12, 2));
            if (nDept != dept_id) return;
            nCntr = int.Parse(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, nSTXPos + 14, 2));
            nServ = int.Parse(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, nSTXPos + 16, 2));
            sQnum = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, nSTXPos + 8, 4);
            string[] sSplit = strData.Split('^');
            string sCusName = sSplit[1];
            //if (_sCommand == "CR") sCusName = " ";
            Console.WriteLine("Dept ID = " + nDept);
            Console.WriteLine("Cntr ID = " + nCntr);
            Console.WriteLine("Serv ID = " + nServ);
            Console.WriteLine("Queue No = " + sQnum);
            Console.WriteLine("Cus Name = " + sCusName);
            var script = string.Format("nextCall(\'{0}\', {1}, {2});", sQnum, nCntr, nServ);
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        CloseSocket();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            //Start receiving again
            if (_serverSocket != null)
                _serverSocket.BeginReceive(_recieveBuffer, 0, _recieveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
            //theDevSock.BeginReceive(_recieveBuffer, 0, _recieveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, theDevSock);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        { }
    }
}

public void CloseSocket()
{
    try
    {
        if (_serverSocket != null)
        {
            if (_serverSocket.Connected)
                _serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            _serverSocket.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    _serverSocket = null;
    sockState = MySocketState.Disconnected;
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("svrDisconnect();");
}
```

My application begin my connecting to the server. After connected to the server, it will start pinging the server. But I found out that everytime after pinging the server using BeginSend, the error "The thread 0x1ff0 has exited with code 259 (0x103)." and the connection to server will be disconnected and my application will retry to connect the server again. Then after connected successfully and when it ping server again, it get disconnected again.

May I know is my coding written correctly? Can I use BeginSend like this to ping server?

Comment: To keep connection alive you can use `SetSocketOption` method, example: `socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);`

Comment: Where should I add this line of coding to? Can you recommend?

Comment: This really depends on how your app logic is, but a general approach would be setting socket option before you connect.

Comment: What do you mean, "keep the connection alive"? TCP can have an open connection with no data whatsoever forever, unless there's something else on the line that breaks it. A bigger problem is that you use no message framing whatsover, which simply will not work with TCP - TCP is a stream-based protocol, not a message-based protocol; you need to add your own messaging protocol if you need messages.

Comment: @raidensan, I try putting it and it has the below error: An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: @Luaan, TCP connection will disconnected if idle or no data transmit or receive for too long right? I want to avoid that happen. How do we do that? Is it pinging the server cannot do it? COM_DeviceIsOnline = "AA".

Comment: TCP itself doesn't care at all - it was designed for the early internet, and there's no point in dropping the connection just because there was a problem between the client and server for a few moments (or hours, or days). The only case where a TCP connection is broken is when you try to send data and don't get a proper response in time (configurable). Unless your application does its own keep-alive, you can pull out the cable, put it back in later and your application will work fine with the same TCP connection. When a (non-keep-alive) TCP connection isn't used, no data is transmitted.

Comment: @Luaan, r u sure if I pull out the cable and put it back later it will work fine? I already tested, if I pull out the cable, my app still show that it is connected to server. I think C# does not have a way to detect unplugged cable unless you send some data to server and expecting a reply. And when I put the cable back, it doesn't receive data from server anymore. Seems like to me it need to do reconnection to server again.

Comment: As far as TCP is concerned, the connection is fine - as long as neither side sent any data while you have been disconnected. It's not just C# - that's how TCP works. When you do send a piece of data while the connection is disrupted, the sending side will know (get an exception in C#), and the connection will be half-open. If this doesn't work for you, it means that some piece of the infrastructure does some extra work on a different level - e.g. a router that keeps track of any "open" TCP connections and terminates them when it detects a problem.

Comment: My application is just a listener. It only receive data from server. It wil not transmit to server. Without pinging/send data to the server constantly, how would my application know there is a disruption in the connection? And that's my question all about. How to do pinging to server?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code to send ping:

```
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pingServer();
    }

    void pingServer()
    {
        if (_serverSocket != null || sockState == MySocketState.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping Server");
            AllBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(COM_DeviceIsOnline);
            //_serverSocket.BeginSend(AllBytes, 0, AllBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
            SendTCPData(0x01, 1, 1, 1, "AA", "");
        }
    }

    public bool SendTCPData(byte bySequenceNo, int nSlaveID, int nDeviceID,
                            int nStatus, String strCommand, String strData)
    {
        return SendTCPData(ACK, bySequenceNo, nSlaveID, nDeviceID, nStatus, strCommand, strData);
    }

    public bool SendTCPData(byte byTypeCode, byte bySequenceNo,
                            int nSlaveID, int nDeviceID,
                            int nStatus, String strCommand,
                            String strData)
    {
        return SendTCPData(byTypeCode, bySequenceNo, nSlaveID, nDeviceID,
                            nStatus, strCommand, strData, 0);
    }

    public bool SendTCPData(byte byTypeCode, byte bySequenceNo,
                            int nSlaveID, int nDeviceID,
                            int nStatus, String strCommand, String strData, int nProtocolType)
    {
        byte[] AllBytes;
        String strTemp;
        try
        {
            strTemp = nSlaveID.ToString("0#") +
              nDeviceID.ToString("0#") +
              nStatus.ToString() +
              strCommand + strData;

            if (nProtocolType == 0)
            {

                AllBytes = new byte[strTemp.Length + 7];
                AllBytes[0] = SOH;
                AllBytes[1] = byTypeCode;
                AllBytes[2] = (byte)((int)bySequenceNo | 0x80);
                AllBytes[3] = STX;
                ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTemp).CopyTo(AllBytes, 4);
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 3] = ETX;
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 2] = 128;
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 1] = EOT;
            }
            else
            {
                AllBytes = new byte[strTemp.Length + 6];
                AllBytes[0] = SOH;
                AllBytes[1] = STX;
                ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTemp).CopyTo(AllBytes, 2);
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 4] = ETX;
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 3] = ETX;
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 2] = 128;
                AllBytes[AllBytes.Length - 1] = EOT;
            }
            //Debug.WriteLine("Sending data to " + _sIPAddr + " -> " + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(AllBytes));
            return SendByte(AllBytes, AllBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return false;

    }

    public bool SendByte(byte[] pByteData, int nLength)
    {
        try
        {
            if  (_serverSocket == null) return false;
            if (!_serverSocket.Connected) return false;
            Console.WriteLine("SendByte = " + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(pByteData, 0, nLength));
            //Debug.WriteLine("SendByte Length= " + nLength.ToString() );
            _serverSocket.BeginSend(pByteData, 0, nLength, SocketFlags.None,
                SendCallback, _serverSocket);
            //dtLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            CloseSocket();

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm using a 30 seconds timer to send ping so as long as it has connection with the server, it will send ping. Now, it can detect unplugged cable already.

May I know what do you guys think about this answer?

Comment: Just that my app after I added the pinging code, when in debug mode, it will occasionally show "The thread 0x??? has exit with code 259". This does not happen before I added the pinging code. is this a concern?